# NavBar and StatusBar in iOS7 acts strange

Tags: ios6, ios7, statusbar, navbar

If I have an "old" app with a NavBar and build it with iOS7, the StatusBar is visible together with the NavBar and it looks like a mess! And if I have a flip view (TransitionStyleFlipHorizontal), that TopBar is placed below the StatusBar and when turning back the view the window jumps up in an ugly way to cover the StausBar again. Do I have to reconstruct everything from scratch to make it look good. Just to make the StausBar stay on top of the NavBar? It must a simple way to fix that but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write below code in your .m file.
It basically help you to change location of navigation bar.

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect tmpFram = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    tmpFram.origin.y += 20;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = tmpFram;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, does not seem to have any effect at all. Not in any .m file or building to see the result in iOS7 or iOS6 simulator

Comment: Strange, it does have effect on the device but when I tried it on the simulator it did not work.

Comment: My fault. It does. Do you have any solution for a TopBar as well? In a alternate view (FlipView)

Comment: I am not getting you, Have you ask question on this site ? if yes then give me link so that i can understand what is your problem and if you havn't ask then i recommend you to post question with image it will more help to understand what actually you want.

Comment: Yes, I will post a new question about that. Tomorrow I hope.

Comment: Give link if you post, If some one can't i will surely help.

Comment: New question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321832/navbar-position-in-alternate-view