# UINavigationBar overlaps on to statusbar ios7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, ios7

I am using UINavigationBar ( without Navigation Controller ) in Xcode 5 with storyboard, my project was working fine without overlapping status-bar since ios 7 status bar structure  has changed in to transparency.

I've tried several way to fix overlapping ( No good result for me ) . I think Apple pushes developers to use Navigation Controller ( Very fascist like  "National Socialist" company )

Is there any way to fix overlapping in ios 7 without Navigation controller class ?

Thank you ...

Comment: Try this solution and let me know is it works for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220982/navbar-and-statusbar-in-ios7-acts-strange/19225604#19225604

Comment: It doesn't work it for me :(

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of answers around, each defines specific behavior. In you case probably you need to set the `edgesForExtendedLayout`. In your VC subclass write:

```
- (UIRectEdge) edgesForExtendedLayout {
return UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

This defines how your VC should behave inside an Apple container VC such as `UITabbarController` or `UINavigationController`, `UIRectEdgeNone` means to not extent below a navbar, tab bar or both. 
This solution is fine also for ios6 since this method in iOS6 is never been called. If you do `self.edgesForExtendedLayout` this will crash on iOS6 since the method isn't supported. I suggest you to use everything but method that will hardcode views or window frames, you'll never know what apple can do next.

Comment: I tried it before , it does not work on my project :( I think it need Navigation Controller class?

Comment: yes it does... for custom container you should use topLayoutGuide. With storyboard you can find them inside your view controller or you can add them programmatically. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html

Comment: Andrea, topLayoutGuide fixed my issue , but it's so lame to changing status bar background colour needs to change complete UIView Background colour.. Is there any alternative way to change it without changing self.view.backgroundColor ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.. you can change the text color, light (white) or dark (black) using the UIStatusBarStyle, but not the color. If you are using a Nav Controller it takes the navbar tint color, I don't know what could happen using just the navbar.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1